# Astrology Program for C++

Tags: c++

Basically The Homework question was to make an Astrology Program. Then There is another part that I am confused about : "Then enhance your program so that if the birthday is only one or two day away from an adjacent sign, the program announces that the birthday is on a "cusp" and also outputs the horoscope adjacent to that sign. This Program will have a long multiway branch. Make up a horoscope for each sign."

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int month, day;
    char ans, space; 

      do
    {
        cout << "Please Enter the Month of your Birthday Follow by the Day(ex. 12/01): \n";
        cin >> month >> space >> day ; 

        if((month == 3 && day >= 21)||(month==4 && day <= 19))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Aries! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 4 && day >= 20)||(month==4 && day <= 20))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Taurus! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 5 && day >= 21)||(month==6 && day <= 21))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Gemini! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 6 && day >= 22)||(month==7 && day <= 22))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Cancer! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 7&& day >= 23)||(month==8 && day <= 22))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Leo! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 8&& day >= 23)||(month==9 && day <= 22))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Virgo! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 9&& day >= 23)||(month==10 && day <= 22))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Libra! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 10&& day >= 23)||(month==11 && day <= 21))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Scorpio! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 11&& day >= 22)||(month==12 && day <= 21))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Saggitarius! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 12&& day >= 22)||(month==1 && day <= 19))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Capricorn! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 1&& day >= 20)||(month==2 && day <= 18))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Aquarius! \n";
           }
        else if((month == 2&& day >= 19)||(month==3 && day <= 20))
           {
              cout << "You Are an Pisces! \n";
           }

        cout << "Would You life to Find Another Horoscope? (Please Type y or Y)\n ";
        cin >> ans;

    } while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

     cout << " Good Bye!\n";   
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to obtain the current month/day in C/C++? Or just looking to have someone complete your homework?

Comment: I believe that the OP is unable to understand what the question means. @user3003168: Refer to the answer I have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly the part of the question you do not understand is not programming related and hence you need to go a bit into detail with regard to astrology for it.

Check these links out and see if you can then understand the question.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_%28astrology%29

It basically adds a simple condition that if the birth date is between two sun signs it lies on a cusp and you need to resolve that condition as well.

That done. I feel you need to code it yourself. That way you will learn. And also try to Google stuff before posting on SO. It is a great way to learn.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Does it have to do with a nested If/Else? Mind giving me little hint?